# How to create a LineChart what contains two CategoryAxis using apache POI?

Tags: java, charts, apache-poi

I'm trying to create an Excel LineChart to compare both dependencies with different number of node points (as on the screenshot). I've tried to just add an extra axis to the graph, but this way gives no result. How is it possible to solve thе problem?

it should look like this:
[image: it should look like this]

```
ChartLegend legend2 = chart2.getOrCreateLegend();
legend2.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);
LineChartData data2 = chart2.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();
ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart2.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
ChartAxis topAxis = chart2.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.TOP);
ValueAxis leftAxis = chart2.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);
ChartDataSource<String> xs = DataSources.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 350, 4, 4));
ChartDataSource<String> xs1 = DataSources.fromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 7, 7));
ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 350, 5, 5));
ChartDataSource<Number> ys2 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 10, 8, 8));
LineChartSeries series1 = data2.addSeries(xs, ys1);
series1.setTitle("1");
LineChartSeries series2 = data2.addSeries(xs1, ys2);
series2.setTitle("2");
chart2.plot(data2, topAxis, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

XSSFChart xssfChart = (XSSFChart) chart2;
CTPlotArea plotArea = xssfChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea();
plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSmooth();
CTBoolean ctBool = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
ctBool.setVal(false);
plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].setSmooth(ctBool);
for (CTLineSer ser : plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSerArray()) {
    ser.setSmooth(ctBool);
}
CTMarker ctMarker = CTMarker.Factory.newInstance();
ctMarker.setSymbol(CTMarkerStyle.Factory.newInstance());
for (CTLineSer ser : plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSerArray()) {
    ser.setMarker(ctMarker);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a `OOXML` chart has multiple axes, then the chart also needs multiple chart data in the plot area. And all axes needs to be pairs. Some of the axes may be invisible but they must be there.

Your code uses old `apache poi` classes which are deprecated and will be removed in next version. So here is an complete example using current `apache poi`version `4.1.0`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.*;

public class XSSFLineChartTwoCatAxes {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("linechart");

   // create data
   Row row;
   Cell cell;
   for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 4; rowIndex++) {
    row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
    if (rowIndex == 0) {
     cell = row.createCell(0);
     cell.setCellValue("CatA");
     for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < 32; colIndex++) {
      cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
      cell.setCellValue(colIndex + (colIndex-1)*11);
     }
    } else if (rowIndex == 1) {
     cell = row.createCell(0);
     cell.setCellValue("ValA");
     for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < 32; colIndex++) {
      cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
      cell.setCellValue(new java.util.Random().nextDouble() * 8 + 1);
     }
    } else if (rowIndex == 2) {
     cell = row.createCell(0);
     cell.setCellValue("CatB");
     for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < 14; colIndex++) {
      cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
      cell.setCellValue(colIndex);
     }
    } else if (rowIndex == 3) {
     cell = row.createCell(0);
     cell.setCellValue("ValB");
     for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < 14; colIndex++) {
      cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
      cell.setCellValue(new java.util.Random().nextDouble() * 8 + 1);
     }
    }
   }

   // creata anchor
   XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 15, 25);

   // create chart
   XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

   // create data sources
   XDDFDataSource<Double> cat1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 1, 31));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 1, 31));
   XDDFDataSource<Double> cat2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 1, 13));
   XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> val2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(3, 3, 1, 13));

   // first line chart

   // create axis
   XDDFCategoryAxis bottomAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   XDDFValueAxis rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
   rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);

   // create data and series
   XDDFLineChartData data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, rightAxis);
   XDDFLineChartData.Series series = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(cat1, val1);
   series.setTitle("CatA", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 0, 0, true, true));
   series.setSmooth(false);
   series.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.NONE);

   chart.plot(data);

   solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.BLUE);

   // second line chart

   // create axis
   XDDFCategoryAxis topAxis = chart.createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.TOP);
   topAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);
   rightAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.RIGHT);
   rightAxis.setVisible(false); // right axis must be there but can be invisible
   rightAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.MAX);

   // set correct cross axis
   topAxis.crossAxis(rightAxis);
   rightAxis.crossAxis(topAxis);

   // create data and series
   data = (XDDFLineChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, topAxis, rightAxis);
   series = (XDDFLineChartData.Series) data.addSeries(cat2, val2);
   series.setTitle("CatB", new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 2, 0, true, true));
   series.setSmooth(false);
   series.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.NONE);

   chart.plot(data);

   // correct the id and order, must not be 0 again because there is a series already in the other chart
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getIdx().setVal(1);
   chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(1).getSerArray(0).getOrder().setVal(1);

   solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.GREEN);

   // create legend
   XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
   legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);
   legend.setOverlay(false);

   // Write the output to a file
   try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-line-chart.xlsx")) {
    wb.write(fileOut);
   }
  }
 }

 private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
  XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
  XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
  line.setFillProperties(fill);
  XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
  XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
  if (properties == null) {
   properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
  }
  properties.setLineProperties(line);
  series.setShapeProperties(properties);
 }
}
```